# Force login on jQuery Mobile/Phonegap app restart

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've got an app running jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 and Phonegap 3.4.0.

It has a login screen so that when you first open the app, you input your info, it does an AJAX check and if all is well, stores your info and moves you past that page.

The ideal scenario, is that everytime the app is sent to the background (the user goes home or switches apps), and then restarts the app they have to login again.

Currently I am accomplishing this in iOS by setting the

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
```

preference in my `config.xml`. I am accomplishing the same thing in Android by using `navigator.app.exitApp();` in a `pause` event listener.

This works well enough usually, but some older versions of android have a weird problem. While going home and restarting the app bring you to the login page, you can just hit the back button and it takes you to the last page you were on before you quit, and you are still logged in. I also have a function that destroys all user variables (rendering all pages useless) when the app pauses, but that also seems to be ignored. On older versions of Android (2.3 specifically), it seems that they are ignoring the `pause` event listener.

How do I fix that, or is there an all around better way of forcing login on restart?

Comment: I put a 'hack' fix for the login-go-back issue, but have you tried listening to the 'resume' event? Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what other requirements you have or what behaviors you might expect from the home page, you could capture the back button event and prevent it from going anywhere.

```
//set a bit or note that you are on the login page
var onHome = true;

...

document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonTap, false);

function backButtonTap(e) {
    if(onHome) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Please Login');
    }
}
```

Certainly not the only or perhaps the best way to handle it since the user appears to stay logged in, which you say is supposed to be wiped out, but it should at least prevent navigating away from the login page and going back.

Comment: I'd like the back button to work, but if you're at the home page, the back button exits the app. I have also used the resume event and it's not worked either.

Comment: So I did like you said, but I changed the function slightly: function onBack(e) {
 alert("running");
 if($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' ) == "login") {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("halted");
  navigator.app.exitApp();
 }
}
I never get an alert, and the back button behavior does nothing. Which brings me back to my original idea that the phone is not behaving properly in regards to listeners.